# How do I get my segment UISegmentedControl to respond?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my ViewController I have added A UISegmentedControl to preform different task for a different selection of the Segmented Control. Its a cards matching game.

And everything seems to work just fine, except that the Segmented Control is not reacting to the selection.., I created a switch to do something in case of "twoCardGame" and in case of "threeCardGame".

From what I understand it would be good to define those variables with enum, which I did in the top part of the controller, but it seems like i'm missing something in it..

Sorry if its not so directed, but my controller is pretty short and simple, would appreciate if you can tell me what am I doing wrong in term of the UISegmentedControl.

Here it is:

```
#import "CardGameViewController.h"
#import "PlayingCardsDeck.h"
#import "CardMatchingGame.h"

enum CardGame {
    twoCardGame,
    threeCardGame
};

@interface CardGameViewController ()


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notificationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreCounter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *cardButtons;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CardMatchingGame *game;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *numberOfCardsToPlayWith;

@end


@implementation CardGameViewController


//creating the getter method that creates a new card game.
- (CardMatchingGame *)game {
    if (!_game) {
        _game = [[CardMatchingGame alloc] initWithCardCount:self.cardButtons.count
                                                  usingDeck:[[PlayingCardsDeck alloc] init]];
        _game.numberOfCardsToPlayWith  = [self selectNumberOfCardsToPlayWith];
    }
    return _game;
}


//creating a setter for the IBOutletCollection cardButtons
-(void)setCardButtons:(NSArray *)cardButtons {
    _cardButtons = cardButtons;
    [self updateUI];
}



- (void)updateUI {

    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isUnplayable;
        cardButton.alpha = card.isUnplayable ? 0.3 : 1.0;

    }
    self.scoreCounter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];
}


//Here I created a method to flipCards when the card is selected, and give the user a random card from the deck each time he flips the card. After each flip i'm incrementing the flipCount setter by one.
- (IBAction)flipCard:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.game flipCardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:sender]];;
    [self updateUI];
}


//sending an alert if the user clicked on new game button
- (IBAction)newGame:(UIButton *)sender {

   UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Think about it for a sec..?" message:@"This will start a new game" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    [mes show];
}


- (NSUInteger)selectNumberOfCardsToPlayWith {
    switch (self.numberOfCardsToPlayWith.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case twoCardGame:
            return 2;
        case threeCardGame:
            return 3;
        default:
            return 2;
    }

    [self updateUI];
}

//preforming an action according to the user choice for the alert yes/no to start a new game
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {

        self.game = nil;
        for (UIButton *button in self.cardButtons) {
            Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:button]];
            card.isUnplayable = NO;
            card.isFaceUp = NO;
            button.alpha = 1;
        }

        self.notificationLabel.text = nil;
        [self updateUI];

    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't see any `addTarget:` calls to segmented control. So you probably set them in Interface Builder. Check IB connections. If everything in IB seems ok -- try to `addTarget:` programmatically.

Comment: I have the selectNumberOfCardsToPlayWith method, that uses the outlet `IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *numberOfCardsToPlayWith;` but what I feel is wrong is something about the enums...like It dosen't look like the select segment knows what button I clicked on @folex

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off creating a selector and adding it to the segmented control target like so:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(selectNumberOfCardsToPlayWith:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (NSUInteger)selectNumberOfCardsToPlayWith:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
        switch (control.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case twoCardGame:
                return 2;
            case threeCardGame:
                return 3;
            default:
                return 2;
        }

        [self updateUI];
}
```

This should work fine.  Using similar code myself currently.

Comment: Or as folex says, check your IB connections are pointing to the correct methods.

Comment: But where this line goes? [segmentedControl addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(selectNumberOfCardsToPlayWith:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
@tim

Comment: @Nir that line can go wherever you create the segment control or when your view loads.  i.e. viewDidLoad

Comment: what i did is draw an action from the storyboard to the controller, and you know how its creating the method with IBAction in parentheses, so I changed that to NSUinteger so it could actually return 2 or 3. is that legal? @Tim

Comment: That's not how it should work.  You link up your IBAction to the UISegmentedControl for the event UIControlEventValueChanged. e.g. - (IBAction)didChangeSegmentedControlIndex:(UISegmentedControl *)control.  You can then access the index using control.selectedSegmentIndex.  If you want to return a NSUInteger, I suggest you programmatically add the target as I stated in my answer.